# scroll to iframe when using a target link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, target

I need to figure out how to combine a target link and an iframe. I use iframes to host videos and use target links for viewers to change the video being played in the iframe, sometimes we have a lot of different questions and the page can get long so I need to figure out how to scroll to the iframe when the link is clicked. I've tried combining anchor tags, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!!

```html
<div class="c-sponsored-landing__main-video">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe name="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274107021?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0"
            webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="c-sponsored-landing__thumbnails">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274107021?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" target="video"><img src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/notalvision/1/seg1.png"
                    class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a>
            <p><strong class="green">Q1:</strong> Why is monitoring intermediate AMD important?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274107111?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" target="video"><img src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/notalvision/1/seg2.png"
                    class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a>
            <p><strong class="green">Q2:</strong> What impact does early Wet AMD detection have on visual outcomes?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274107379?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" target="video"><img src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/notalvision/1/seg3.png"
                    class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a>
            <p><strong class="green">Q3:</strong> If the goal is early Wet AMD detection to help prevent vision loss,
                then how are we doing?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274133949?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" target="video"><img src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/notalvision/1/seg4.png"
                    class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"></a>
            <p><strong class="green">Q4:</strong> What impact does severe vision loss have on a patient's quality of
                life? </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live link: https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/notalvision/1/index3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the video and listen to the click event on the links, once the click event is triggered, prevent the normal behaviour and use *scrollIntoView* to show the video.

```
const video = document.getElementById("video")
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a")

links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // LOGIC TO CHANGE THE VIDEO
    video.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dupftwqa/1/

Comment: The scroll is working, but now the iframe isn't updating with the new video.

Comment: You have to add the logic to change the link where I put the comment, my code was just an example of how to do the scroll.

Comment: I posted a new code below. Where do I put the logic? Am I putting the url link in the java below?

Comment: You can put the logic anywhere after e.preventDefault(), the idea was for you to add the logic where I put the comment `// LOGIC TO CHANGE THE VIDEO`

Answer (score 0):

The scroll is working, but now the iframe isn't updating with the new video.

```
    <div class="c-sponsored-landing__main-video" id="video">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe allowfullscreen="" class="embed-responsive-item" mozallowfullscreen="" name="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303509941?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
    </div>

    <div class="c-sponsored-landing__thumbnails">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row grey-box1">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303509941?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" target="video"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/aerie/1/1-simmons.png" /></a>
                        <p class="text-center small"><strong>Steve Simmons, MD</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303547792?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" target="video"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/aerie/1/1-singh.png" /></a>
                        <p class="text-center small"><strong>Inder Paul Singh, MD</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <h4>How does Rhopressa<sup>&reg;</sup> address some of the key considerations in the medical management of glaucoma?</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row grey-box3">

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303547723?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" target="video"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/aerie/1/1-singh.png" /></a>
                        <p class="text-center small"><strong>Inder Paul Singh, MD</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303349557?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" target="video"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.visioncareprofessional.com/digital/aerie/1/1-radcliffe.png" /></a>
                        <p class="text-center small"><strong>Nathan Radcliffe, MD</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Why does the mechanism of action of Rhopressa<sup>&reg;</sup> make it a significant addition to the therapeutic armamentarium for glaucoma?</h4>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
const video = document.getElementById("video")
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a")

links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // LOGIC TO CHANGE THE VIDEO
    video.scrollIntoView({block: 'nearest',  behavior: 'smooth' });
  })
})
</script>
```